# Can I create two different class/interface divided by property value?

Tags: typescript

I have a `Selection` class(or can be an interface, I don't care).

`Selection` class can have`coverage` property with `'all' | 'selected'`.

If `coverage` is `'selected'`, it can have `items` value, which is an array.

I want it cannot have `items` if its `coverage` is `'all'`.

#### With code samples I want:

```js
const allSelected: Selected = {
  coverage: 'all',
};

allSelected.items = []; // I wish this could emit error, because it tried to access `items`.

const onlySelected: Selected = {
  converage: 'selected', // I wish this could emit error, because it does not have `items`.
}
```

Is this `Selection` class can be defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) `type`:

```
type Selected = {
    coverage: "selected",
    items: string[]
} | {
    coverage: "all"
};
```

All of your example code will emit errors where you expect.

In order to access items, you need to ensure that `coverage === "selected"`, for example:

```
function test(selection: Selected) {
   // selection.items; // ERROR, might not have an `items` prop
   if(selection.coverage === "selected") {
       console.log(selection.coverage); // OK
   }
}
```

There's no way to do this with the `interface` keyword, but `type` and `interface` are 99% the same thing anyway.